# PowerBI Service unable to render visuals from Python Script Scatteplots using dates on x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, powerbi, office365, powerapps

PowerBI Service does not appear to be able to render Python Script visuals that I can render via PowerBI Desktop (using Python 3.6) without problems where I require the use of dates in the x-axis of Seaborn scatterplot.

**What are the possible reasons for this?**

The result of running my code in PowerBI Desktop (running Python 3.6) appears as

[image]

However, the visual looks like this when published via PowerBI Service (Python Version unknown)

[image]

Notice how the x-axis and the y-axis are completely incorrect and the legend is not working for the colour coding and shapes.

Special Notes:

- I am publishing to a Power BI Service under Pro Subscription
- When I publish basic Python Scripts like those covered in Microsoft documentation I have no problem
- The underlying data set is from a CSV file ingested via Power Query and is not a Python generated data set ie data frame. The dataset seen in my script is that which is generated via the use of the Python Script visualisation feature of PowerBI.

The script I am using is as follows:

```
# The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as a preamble for your script: 

# dataset = pandas.DataFrame(EmployeeName, Event_Date, RerunCount, AMPCPUTIME, Client_App)

from matplotlib import dates as mpl_dates
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Prepare date for matplotlib
dataset['Event_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Event_Date'])  # This line is critical to fixing the x-axis for Event Date

plt.clf() #clears plot

# plot the data
sns.scatterplot(x='Event_Date', y='AMPCPUTIME',hue='RerunCount', style='Client_App',s=120, data=dataset, palette='bright') 

# after plotting the data, format the labels
# X-axis  Formatting
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
date_format = mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%y')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(15))
plt.xticks(fontsize=12, color = 'white')
plt.xlabel("Date of Execution", size=20, labelpad = 20, color = 'white')

# Y-axis  Formatting
plt.yticks(fontsize=16,color = 'white')
plt.ylabel("CPU Usage", size=20, labelpad = 20, color = 'white')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y') # This is necessary to prevent scientific notation occuring on y-axis
current_values = plt.gca().get_yticks()
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['{:,.0f}'.format(x) for x in current_values])

# Set Size of Plot
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(20, 10)


# Set Legend for plot
plt.legend(
    markerscale=3, 
    fontsize='medium', 
    title_fontsize='14', 
    loc='center left', 
    bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), 
    labelspacing = 2, 
    ncol =1, 
    )

# Set background colour
plt.axes().set_facecolor("#385870")
plt.gcf().set_facecolor("#385870")

# Apply Title to Plot
#plt.title(str(dataset['EmployeeName'].unique())[2:-2], pad = 20, fontsize='18')
# Reduce padding around cell
plt.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

Comment: this link, nearly 3 years old suggests that Python version is for PowerBI, at least 3.7.1
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/python-visualizations-in-power-bi-service/
" The initial version of the Python runtime supported in Power BI includes versions 2.7.15 and 3.7.1. We will periodically update the runtime to keep it current. "     But i guess it is more to do with the complexity of your plot than the Python version that is causing the service version to render incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

[Previously answered.](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Python-DateTimeIndex-not-showing-in-PowerBI/m-p/601809)

More people are experiencing issues with their column index going loco.
Take a look at this post, it should clear things up for you.